# Stage, release and production server docker containers in single VPS

Tags: docker, server, cloud, digital-ocean

Currently, we are using a $5 USD droplet with containers acting as stage, release candidate and production server each. We are a small team of (enthusiasts) developers with limited resources looking for value for money setup and scalability.

- What are we missing by not going to 3 droplets for each server setup?
- What other approach/technologies can we apply to answer this
  limitations and juice-up this 1 droplet setup?
- When will be the time
  that we need to pursue the 3 droplets setup?

We are not limited to the $5 USD droplet, we consider upgrading to higher price droplet.

We are using ubuntu, jetty, java, reactjs, cassandra, nginx, docker and considering shifting from java to rust for our backend

Comment: What's your main technology? Java? Golang is perfect for your case

Comment: java, we are also looking forward to using rust in the server-side.